# Docker Swarm creating real cluster: Registered and Removed

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I was recently playing with Docker and just discovered Swarm. In my scenario I've two hosts (*irons*) with Ubuntu where docker is installed and a laptop (*osx*)

- host1 docker-node (212.x.x.1)
- host2 docker-node (212.x.x.2)
- laptop docker-cli + swarm

I'm trying to create a cluster with the two docker-nodes so, in laptop:

```
$ swarm create
TOKEN_ID
$ swarn join token://TOKEN_ID --addr=212.x.x.1
INFO[0000] Registering on the discovery service every 20s...  addr=212.x.x.1:2375 discovery=token://TOKEN_ID
Ctrl+C    
$ swarn join token://TOKEN_ID --addr=212.x.x.2
INFO[0000] Registering on the discovery service every 20s...  addr=212.x.x.2:2375 discovery=token://TOKEN_ID
Ctrl+C
```

Then I'm creating the *swarm-manager* in the laptop too, to manage the cluster:

```
$ swarm manage token://TOKEN_ID --host=0.0.0.0:4243
```

If I immediately list the nodes they are appearing both:

```
$ swarm list token://TOKEN_ID
212.x.x.1
212.x.x.2
```

But after a minute (or so) they're not appearing at all:

```
$ swarm list token://TOKEN_ID
$
```

And if I try to install any container in the cluster it says:

```
$ docker -H 0.0.0.0:4243 run -dP nginx
ERRO[0067] HTTP error: No healthy node available in the cluster  status=500
Error response from daemon: No healthy node available in the cluster
```

Note, if I run the *swarm manage* with *-debug* option it says something about:

```
INFO[0002] Registered Engine 212.x.x.1:2375
(after about a minute)
INFO[0041] Removed Engine 212.x.x.1:2375
```

Any clue about what could be happening here?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexandre Beslic (@abronan) said to me on IRC, "nodes are heartbeating to the discovery service through the `swarm join` command (in the logs you should see 'node registering every XXX seconds'), if the node is not taking part in the cluster it will be removed because it is attached to a TTL value (if this value falls to 0 the entry is removed).". So, question solved.